# find fprint append to file instead of truncate

Tags: bash, find, printf

According to the man page of `find`, -fprint and -fprintf will truncate the output file if it exists:

```
   -fprint file
          True; print the full file name into file file.  If file does not exist when find is run,
          it is created; if it does exist, it is truncated.   The  file  names  `/dev/stdout'  and
          `/dev/stderr'  are  handled  specially;  they  refer to the standard output and standard
          error output, respectively.  ...
```

Is there a way to use -fprint to append to an existing file instead of truncating it?  I'm planning to use `-print -delete >> "$logFile"` since I can't find how to use `-fprint` to print to `$logFile` without truncating the file first, but it seems more elaborate to use the -fprint options.

Answer (score 2):

You could use process substitution to send it to a command that appends to the file.

```
-fprint >(cat >>"$logFile")
```

Another solution would be to write to a new file, then append that file to the log file.

```
find ... -delete -fprint /tmp/logfile.$$
cat /tmp/logfile.$$ >> "$logFile" && rm /tmp/logfile.$$
```

But I'm not sure why you feel the need to use `-fprint` instead of just redirecting the output of the whole command. `-fprint` is mainly useful if you want to send different output to different files, e.g.

```
find -type d -fprint allDirs -o -type f -fprint allFiles
```

Comment: That is the main reason I'm interested in finding alternative options.  Since using -fprint can write to multiple files while my solution of -print -delete >> outFile can only write to one.  Thanks for the option of process substitution.  I wonder if that's the most efficient option for this?

Comment: Another option would be to write to a temporary file, then append that file to the logfile.